# Help with $\int_{\Bbb D}(x^2 - y^2)\, dx\, dy$ where $\Bbb D=\{|x|+|y|\le2\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

Consider $\Bbb D=\{|x|+|y|\le2\}$; I'm trying to solve:
$$\int_{\Bbb D}(x^2 - y^2)\, dx\, dy$$

---

My goal is to solve that through a **change of variables**.
I was thinking to something like: $\begin{cases} |x|=u^2 \\ |y|=v^2 \end{cases}$. In such a case I would had the new domain as a circle; but the transformation is not invertible and I should study case by case: $\{x+y\le 2,x\ge0,y\ge0\},\{x-y\le2,x\ge0,y\le0\},\{-x+y\le2,x\le0, y\ge0\},\{-x-y\le2,x\le0,y\le0\}$.
Now, another transformation that would fit the problem is: $\begin{cases} x+y=u \\ x-y=v \end{cases}$, but I wasn't able to write any single domain in a comfortable way.

---

Is there another suitable change of variables?
(otherwise) an someone handle one of the transformation I just proposed?

Comment: Of course you should know how to evaluate this by computation, but it's worth thinking about the fact that $\int_D x^2\,dA = \int_D y^2\,dA$ because the region is symmetric about the line $y=x$. So no computation whatsoever is required. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, the area under integration is a tilted square (with corners at (2,0), (0,2), (-2,0) and (0,-2). The sides of this square are  given by the lines :$x-y=2, x-y =-2, x+y=2, x+y=-2$. Also, the integrand can be factored as: $x^2 - y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$

Thus, choosing $u=x-y$ and $v=x+y$ seems a natural choice here.

Then, we use: $${\iint\limits_R {f\left( {x,y} \right)dxdy}  } = {\iint\limits_S {f\left[ {x\left( {u,v} \right),y\left( {u,v} \right)} \right]  }\kern0pt{  \left| {\frac{{\partial \left( {x,y} \right)}}{{\partial \left( {u,v} \right)}}} \right|dudv} ,}$$

where,$\left| {\large\frac{{\partial \left( {x,y} \right)}}{{\partial \left( {u,v} \right)}}\normalsize} \right|= \left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} {\frac{{\partial x}}{{\partial u}}}&{\frac{{\partial x}}{{\partial v}}}\\{\frac{{\partial y}}{{\partial u}}}&{\frac{{\partial y}}{{\partial v}}} \end{array}} \right|$

For this term, use $x=\frac{u+v}{2}$ and $y=\frac{v-u}{2}$. Getting, $\left| {\large\frac{{\partial \left( {x,y} \right)}}{{\partial \left( {u,v} \right)}}\normalsize} \right| = 1/2$

So we get, $I = \int_{u=-2}^2 \int_{v=-2}^2 \frac{uv}{2} du dv$ Which pretty easily evaluates out to $0$.

Comment: How did you say $(-2 \le x+y \le 2)$, $(-2 \le x-y \le 2)$?

Comment: @DOmonoXYLEDyL I said that because as the the new coordinator system, the area D (Tilted square) is bounded by the lines u=2, u=-2 v=2 and v=-2 (as mentioned in 1st para). And as we want to integrate over the square, I want both u and v to independently vary between the 2 boundaries so integrate from -2 to 2.

Comment: If I want to derivate that without any supposition about the shape of the domain, observe $\{x+y\le2\} \rightarrow \{v\le2\}$ and $\{-x-y\le2\} \rightarrow \{v\ge-2\}$ would be sufficient to state $-2\le v \le 2$?

Comment: Fair enough. But such questions heavily depend on such graphs and visual aids.

Answer (score 3):

The integral is $0$ because the domain is symmethric relative to coordinate change $(x,y)\to (y,x)$ therefore
$$\int_{\Bbb D}x^2\, \mathrm{d}x\, \mathrm{d}y=
\int_{\Bbb D}y^2\, \mathrm{d}x\, \mathrm{d}y.$$

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral_%28-2%29%5E0+integral_%28-2-x%29%5E%282%2Bx%29+%28x%5E2-y%5E2%29+dy+dx+%2B+integral_0%5E2+integral_%28x-2%29%5E%282-x%29+%28x%5E2-y%5E2%29+dy+dx) direct computation gives $0$ also.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend your second change of variables. For this choice of $u,v$, we find that $$
\mathbb D = \{x,y: -1 \leq u(x,y) \leq 1, -1 \leq v(x,y) \leq 1\},
$$
and we find that
$$
x^2 - y^2 = u(x,y)v(x,y).
$$

Answer (score 0):

The domain is the square with vertices $(0,2),(-2,0),(0,-2),(2,0),$ and satisfies $$\begin{aligned}-x-2&\leq y \leq -x+2\\
x-2&\leq y \leq x+2\end{aligned}$$
From this $$-2\leq x+y \leq 2 \quad \text{and} \quad -2 \leq y-x \leq 2.$$